# Linked PDF and going back in OS X Preview

Tags: pdf, preview

When I click on a linked reference in a PDF it jumps to the bibliography at the end of the paper. 
Is there an easy way to jump back to the passage I just read?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Preview can do this, once you have followed a link <kbd>Cmd-[</kbd>  will take you "Back" to the page where the link was clicked. Additionally if you wish to follow the link again using your keyboard, the obvious shortcut for "Forward" is then <kbd>Cmd-]</kbd>.

Both of these may be found under the "Go" menu in Preview.

Comment: Amazing! thank you so very much! Thousands of hours saved!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the "Go to" menu and the Back option there.

With a Swiss German keyboard, it's <kbd>Cmd-Ö</kbd> but that won't you help much :-)

Comment: It does help in germany ...